# array data not being sent to API controller c#

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am working on angularJS application where I am making post call to send data to API controller everything is being sent to controller apart from array of data.

Here is code to make controller call

```
this.UpdateJobWithDeadlines = function (JobData) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/JobAPI/UpdateJobWithDeadlines",
        data: JSON.stringify(JobData)
    });
    return request;
}
```

I have checked the JobData object, it's value (indented for easier reading) is:

```
{
    "jobNum":null,
    "jobName":"fgfg",
    /* snip */
    "StatusDatas":[
        {
            "scId":0,
            "JobNum":9746.030148450296,
            "StatusComment":"03-03-2017 : 1",
            "scTimeStamp":"2017-03-03T15:47:48.174Z",
            "IsNew":0
        },
        {
            "scId":0,
            "JobNum":8527.946898255957,
            "StatusComment":"03-03-2017 : 3",
            "scTimeStamp":"2017-03-03T15:47:49.459Z",
            "IsNew":0
        }
    ],
    /* SNIP */
    "telephone":"9"
}
```

The controller method signature is as below:

```
public int UpdateJobWithDeadlines(JobDataWithDeadlines JobData)
```

And the `JobDataWithDeadlines` class is as below:

```
public class JobDataWithDeadlines
{
    public int? jobNum;
    public string jobName;
    /* snip */
    public List<StatusData> StatusDatas;
}

public class StatusData
{
    public int scId;
    public int JobNum;

    public string StatusComment;

    public string scTimeStamp;

    public bool IsNew;
}
```

But I am getting an empty list for the `StatusDatas` property of the controller method parameter.

Comment: have you tried [FormBody ] JobDataWithDeadlines JobData

Comment: Side Note: use `double` for `Jobnum` ;).

Comment: i think your json is not correct in the StatusDatas part

Comment: Is that a copy/paste error? `telephone` only has a single set of quotes on the right.

Comment: @Igor that was my mistake while editing. Corrected it.

Comment: Your valid json should look like this telephone is extra .  

   {
      "jobNum": null,
      "jobName": null,
      "StatusDatas": [

    {
      "scId": 0,
      "JobNum": 0,
      "StatusComment": null,
      "scTimeStamp": null,
      "IsNew": false
    }
       ]
    }

Comment: also note datatype for JobNum is it int you want to double

Comment: It's usually better to test your api separately from the client. Use rest console or one of the other chrome addons/extensions. Once you know whats required to get your API working... then you'll know it's a JS issue if you have trouble calling it from JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your fields, they all need to be properties instead. The deserialization and serialization for `json.net` will not bind to fields (*out of the box anyways, it is possible with additional configuration / custom mapping code*).

```
public class JobDataWithDeadlines
{
    public int? jobNum {get;set;}
    public string jobName {get;set;}
    /* snip */
    public List<StatusData> StatusDatas {get;set;}
}

public class StatusData
{
    public int scId {get;set;}
    public double JobNum {get;set;}
    public string StatusComment {get;set;}
    public string scTimeStamp {get;set;}
    public bool IsNew {get;set;}
}
```

Also you should specify the `content-type` in the http header of the request. In this case set it to `application/json`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following properties to the object you pass to the `$http` method:

```
this.UpdateJobWithDeadlines = function (JobData) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/api/JobAPI/UpdateJobWithDeadlines",
        data: JSON.stringify(JobData)
    });
    return request;
}
```

You can optionally specify a charset to the content type, i.e.:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

Some people also suggest adding `traditional: true` to it, but in my experience that is not always what causes this problem.